# Layout changes are not reflecting in the application

Tags: android, layout, button, android-layout, imagebutton

I have created a button widget with custom images by referring [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton) article. I have set images for onclick and onfocus. But I can only see the normal image for the button, nothing changes when I focus or press the button.

Here is my code:

**custom_button.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_reload_4" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_reload_2"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_reload_3"
        android:state_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

**Layout:**

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/reload_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
```

Images are placed in the drawable folder. I m not sure why its not working. I have also faced issues with the layout,ie I can see the changes in the eclipse when selecting the 'layout' tab but its not shown in the application after updating it. Can anyone help me on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector should be like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_reload_2"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_reload_3"
        android:state_focused="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_reload_4" />
</selector>
```

I.e. you have to place the default `item` to the end. It seems that android inflates this like a `switch-case` block.

Comment: Thank you!!.. That was my mistake that I havn't followed the documentation thoroughly :)

Comment: I have also noticed that for some cases the changes are shown in the eclipse (layout tab) but not in the application. For eg: I have 3 headers in a layout. I have set the background of all the 3 headers with the color value defined in the strings.xml I can see the changes in the eclipse but in my application, the change is applied to the first header. Do u have any idea?